# How can I share the internet connection of my HTC Wildfire ( Android 2.2 ) via  Bluetooth or USB?

Tags: bluetooth, tethering, htc-wildfire, usb-tethering, bluetooth-tethering

I have HTC Wildfire and has Android 2.2 installed on it.

I have internet (GPRS,3G) on mobile. I want to share to my computer as windows XP.

Tried to figure out it first on other questions but didn't found the answer.

How could I share mobiles internet on XP PC ? (Please PC doesn't have wi-fi as its PC. May be some way to share via bluetooth OR USB)

Thanks,

Comment: Or you may suggest it via USB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For USB teathering i know only two options that (in my experience) works well:

[AziLink - The hard but free way](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=704375)

[EasyTeather - The easy but non-free way](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.mstream.easytether_polyclef&hl=en)