# How to tether an Android phone to a PC via Bluetooth?

Tags: wi-fi, bluetooth, bluetooth-tethering

When wifi connecting to the internet via an Android mobile, how can I get access to this internet connection over Bluetooth from my computer?

Comment: Related: [Tethering options for the laptop and the phone](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/48240/16575) / [How can I share the internet connection of my HTC Wildfire ( Android 2.2 ) via Bluetooth or USB?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/14356/16575) / [Android to Android Bluetooth Tether](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/49852/16575). For more, please see [questions tagged bluetooth-tethering](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bluetooth-tethering).

Answer (score 0):

Under `Settings`, `Network & Internet`, `Hotspot & tethering` enable `Bluetooth tethering`. Then, if you haven't already, pair your computer with your phone and connect.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Windows, you should be able to right-click the Bluetooth icon in your taskbar, and select the option to join an Bluetooth network (May be named different)